# Wordpress wp_check_password c#

Tags: c#, wordpress

I need to check if a Wordpress user login/password are correct from c#.
I see the password are encrypted. 
I wonder how I can perform the test from c#.
There's a method called wp_check_password (in the pluggable.php page), but I don't know how to translate this code into c#.

Any help?

Comment: Hey, I ran into the same issue yesterday, but didn't find a good solution for using the hash and salt values of `wp-config.php`. Could you please provide your solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read through the wordpress code to figure out the hash algorithm they are using. Replicate that in your C# program. Then compare this hash against the WP database's user table.